# adding element to xml file from c#.net

Tags: c#, xml

how to add element to a xml file using asp.net& c#.net inweb application

Comment: It'd be helpful if you were a bit more specific about the element you want to add, perhaps giving us a sample of the file you want to modify? =)

Comment: Are you using Linq to XML or some thing ? Just asking ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of adding a new element to the root node:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
doc.Root.Add(new XElement("someNode", "some node value"));
doc.Save("test.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the document using XmlDocument class and then modify it as needed. Reference documentation and examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument_members.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XmlDocument.CreateElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createelement(VS.71).aspx) method to create it and then to append it